# Что означает оператор as?

Tags: haskell, функциональное-программирование

Только начал изучать этот язык программирования. Читаю учебник: [Ссылка](http://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/book/2.html)
Там есть такой код. Как я понял "as" это не просто название переменной, а какое-то ключевое слово, т.к. в учебнике оно подсвечивается не как обычная переменная.

```
instance Show Time where
    show (Time h m s) = show h ++ ":" ++ show m ++ ":" ++ show s

instance Show Hour where
    show (Hour h) = addZero (show h)

instance Show Minute where
    show (Minute m) = addZero (show m)

instance Show Second where
    show (Second s) = addZero (show s)

addZero :: String -> String
addZero (a:[]) = '0' : a : []
addZero as     = as
```

Собственно, что это за оператор такой в конце кода, и зачем он нужен?

Comment: @0xdb Мне кажется, что зря убрали `в haskell` из названия темы - так оно слишком общее, а `as` в разных языках делает совсем разные вещи

Comment: @MBo Тема исключителъно только о haskell. В других вопросах с другими ЯП и операторами из 1-го 2-ух символов тоже самое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово `as` в языке Haskell используется для именованного импорта модулей, например:

```
import qualified Data.List as L
```

К членам такого модуля затем можно обращаться через точку, например:

```
L.sort [5,4,3]
```

Однако в коде, который вы привели, `as` - это не ключевое слово, а обычная переменная. По традиции такая нотация с `s` на конце используется для обозначения множественности. То есть `as` - это когда много `a`.

В данном случае, слово `as` - это идентификатор аргумента функции `addZero`. Эта функция определена в два приёма:

1. Если аргумент - это список, содержащий ровно один элемент, который мы назовём `a`, то результат функции - список из двух элементов - `'0'` и `a`.
2. Если аргумент - любой другой список, который мы назовём `as`, то результат функции есть сам этот список.

Я думаю, что в учебнике это слово "подсвечивается" потому, что алгоритм подсвечивания не проводит полного синтаксического анализа, а лишь сличает со списком ключевых слов.

Для справки, полный список ключевых слов можно посмотреть на [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords).